# How to make more MapHttpRoutes for MVC 4 Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have 2 API routes for my API atm, but I want to add more, and the way I am doing it it seems to overwrite each other, so in the code I pasted, only the `CreateUser` route works.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "CreateUser",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{cUser}",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "User",
            action = "CreateUser",
            cUser = RouteParameter.Optional
        });
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "AllGames",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{playerId}",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Game",
            action = "GetAllGames",
            playerId = RouteParameter.Optional
        });
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        });
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe the pattern `api/{controller}/{cUser}` in "CreateUser" route is matching with rest of the controller actions because of its more generic pattern. Use specific controller name in the routes as "User" (api/User/{cUser}) and "Game" (api/Game/{playerId}). The more specific routes should be at the top and more generic at the bottom.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "CreateUser",
    routeTemplate: "api/User/{cUser}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "User",
        action = "CreateUser",
        cUser = RouteParameter.Optional
    }
);

routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "AllGames",
    routeTemplate: "api/Game/{playerId}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Game",
        action = "GetAllGames",
        playerId = RouteParameter.Optional
    }
);
```