# How to define a DelegatingHandler for custom route?

Tags: c#, delegatinghandler

I've created a DelegatingHandler and it works for every request. I've read some articles that i can define a handler for a specific route but I've tried a lot of ways without success, i'm missing something that i didn't found what is.

The last attempt was:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "SaveMessage",
    routeTemplate: "api/message/{type}",
    defaults: new { type = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: null,
    handler: HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(
              new HttpControllerDispatcher(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration), 
              new DelegatingHandler[]{new ValidationHandler()})
);
```

My class Controller and method has the follow attributes:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/message")]
public class MessageController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{type}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Save(string type, [FromBody] Message message)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

What is missing to my handler only works on requests like **api/message/text**?

I've read links like [How to make more MapHttpRoutes for MVC 4 Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766157/how-to-make-more-maphttproutes-for-mvc-4-api) and http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection.

Comment: So are you saying your delegatingHandler works on api/message/text routes? I think you have added the Handler to that route so that's how it should work then..

Comment: No, it only works if i do something like **GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new ValidationHandler())** but every request hits the handler and i would like **only** request api/message/text hit the handler.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the constraints that is set to null.
You should define it like this for making it work for POST or GET:

```
constraints: new { httpMethod = new System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) }
```

Comment: If i have a query string like api/message/text?token=XXXX, should i add it to route config?

Comment: No, Querystrings are not part of the route

Comment: Here is what my browser submit "http://local.mycompany.com.ar/IntegrationApi/api/message/text?token=a5e56f178". I've tried to add IntegrationApi too but no lucky.